# filecmp returns False even though files are equal

Tags: python, file-comparison

I'm trying to compare between two files with `filecmp`, the problem is that the result is always `"No, the files are NOT the same"` which means `False`
even though the files are the same.

I'm writing to two different files the same content. First I write to file `revision_1.txt`:

```
original_stdout = sys.stdout
with open('revision_1.txt', 'w') as rev1:
       sys.stdout = rev1
       print(revision)  # revision is output from command i took before
sys.stdout = original_stdout

if filecmp.cmp('revision_1.txt', 'revision_2.txt'):
    # revision_2.txt is file I c
    print("Both the files are same")
else:
    # Do whatever you want if the files are NOT the same
    print("No, the files are NOT the same")

original_stdout = sys.stdout
with open('revision_2.txt', 'w') as rev2:
       sys.stdout = rev2
       print(revision)  # revision is output from command i took before
sys.stdout = original_stdout
```

My goal is if the files are equal - stop the script. If they are not, it will rewrite `revision_2.txt` and then send mail, (I already wrote the code for mail).

Comment: Why do you manipulate `sys.stdout` so much? Why not just do `file.write(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of files us unusual:

```
import filecmp

revision = "08/15"

with open('revision_1.txt', 'w') as rev1:
      rev1.write(revision)

with open('revision_2.txt', 'w') as rev2:
      rev2.write(revision)

with open('revision_3.txt', 'w') as rev3:
      rev3.write(revision + "-42")

# should compare equal
if filecmp.cmp('revision_1.txt', 'revision_2.txt'):
    print("Identical")
else:
    print("No, the files are NOT the same")

# should NOT compare equal
if filecmp.cmp('revision_1.txt', 'revision_3.txt'):
    print("Identical")
else:
    print("No, the files are NOT the same")
```

prints

```
Identical
No, the files are NOT the same
```

Comment: How can can ignore message-id (I only need the Revision value) ?

Comment: ` Not equal
<rpc-reply message-id="urn:uuid:61dfe2cc-cf0a-40ad-855d-b28392ac151c">
  <output>
Revision: fpc1-1603878922-228
</output>
</rpc-reply>

FFFFFFF
<rpc-reply message-id="urn:uuid:0694a78b-23ab-4fe7-865f-b7f164e0dad9">
  <output>
Revision: fpc1-1603878922-228
</output>
</rpc-reply>

FFFFFFF
`

Answer (score 0):

Try set shallow to false (Default is True), i.e

```
if filecmp.cmp('revision_1.txt', 'revision_2.txt', shallow=False):
```

From the documentation:
If shallow is true, files with identical os.stat() signatures are taken to be equal. Otherwise, the contents of the files are compared.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html#filecmp.cmp

Comment: It might help to add a small explanation on what that argument is supposed to do

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the reply
As I said I'm very new with Python
According to your recommendations I changed the code, this time I'm going to send the full script and explain

I successes to compare between 'revision' and 'd' my problem is that I'm getting different rpc-reply message-id,

How can can ignore message-id (I only need the Revision value) ?

See script output:
Not equal


Revision: fpc1-1603878922-228

FFFFFFF


Revision: fpc1-1603878922-228

FFFFFFF

Script:

```
import smtplib
import email.message
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from ncclient import manager
from ncclient.xml_ import *
import sys
import time
import filecmp

# Connecting to juniper cc-vc-leg
conn = manager.connect(
        host='10.1.1.1',
        port='830',
        username='test',
        password='test',
        timeout=10,
        device_params={'name':'junos'},
        hostkey_verify=False)

# Take juniper commands
resault = conn.command('show version | match Hostname', format='text')
revision = conn.command('show system commit revision', format='text')
compare_config = conn.compare_configuration(rollback=1)

# Open & read file vc-lg_rev.text
f = open('vc-lg_rev.text', 'r')
d = f.read()

# Check if revision output is equal to file "vc-lg_rev.text"
# If equal exit the script
if  (revision == d):
       print('equal')
       exit()
       print('I hop script stopped')
else:
       print('Not equal')
       print(revision)
       print('FFFFFFF')
       print(d)
       print('FFFFFFF')

# To save last revision number to "vc-lg_rev.text"
with open('vc-lg_rev.text', 'w', buffering=1) as rev1:
        rev1.write(str(revision))
        rev1.flush()
rev1.close()


# This is how i copy "compare_config" output to file "vc-lg_compare.text"
original_stdout = sys.stdout
with open('vc-lg_compare.text', 'w') as a:
        sys.stdout = a
        print(compare_config)
sys.stdout = original_stdout

def send_email(compare):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('techunix.technion.ac.il', 25)
    email_reciver = 'rafish@technion.ac.il', 'rafi1shemesh@gmail.com'
    message = f"'Subject': mail_subject \n\n {compare}"
    ID = 'Juniper_Compare'
    server.sendmail(ID, email_reciver, message)

with open('vc-lg_compare.text', 'r') as compare:   # "as" means file object called compare
        text = str(compare.read())                 # I want to recive the output as string to look specific word in the file
        if (text.find('+') > -1) or (text.find('- ') > -1):
                send_email(text)
```